# concatenating strings into array of char in c++(by using less strcat)

Tags: c++, linux, string, char

For example, I have a code like this.

```
    char NameTmp[] = "foo.txt";
    char Name[] = "bar.txt"
    char cmd[80] = "./analyzeText ";
    strcat(cmd, Name);
    strcat(cmd, " ");
    strcat(cmd, NameTmp);
    strcat(cmd, " ");
    strcat(cmd, "8");
    system(cmd);
```

Basically, I am trying to call "./analyzeText bar.txt foo.txt 8" on linux on my program. analyzeText is program already made and is in the same folder.

I'm wondering is there a shorter way than to use "strcat" to make strings in c++?

Comment: If you just want to call another program, this seems like a job for a shell script.  Is there any reason you can't use a script, or want to use C?

Comment: @dappawit: You're making some pretty sweeping assumptions there.  There may be any number of reasons that the OP wants to execute a system command from inside an application.

Comment: Yes you're right.  When I first saw it I read it as though he *only* wanted to call the other program.  I didn't think that it might be within a larger program itself.  My mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use some strings:

```
std::string NameTmp = "foo.txt";
std::string Name = "bar.txt";
std::string cmd = "./analyzeText " + Name + " " + NameTemp + " 8";
system(cmd.c_str());
```

It's slightly less efficient (more strings are created), but it's much simpler.

Comment: It is more efficient if it just works, and you don't have to ask questions about it.:-)

Answer (score 3):

```
std::string cmd("./analyzeText ");
cmd += Name;
// etc.
system(cmd.c_str());
```

The right argument to `+=` may be a C string (`const char *`/literal), a `std::string` or a single character.

(Please don't ever use `strcat` in C++; it's unnecessary and insecure.)

Comment: May I ask why strcat is insecure?

Comment: @js0823: `strcat` will happily write over the trailing `\0` or past the end of the buffer, so if you don't calculate your final string's size to the last byte precisely, it provokes Undefined Behavior. `+=` on a `std::string` will do memory allocation for you if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use C++ constructs:

```
std::string nameTmp = "foo.txt";
std::string name    = "bar.txt";
int param = 8;

...

std::stringstream ss;
ss << "./analyzeText " << name << " " << nameTmp << " " << param;
system(ss.str().c_str());
```

I'm assuming that the names and parameter are variable at run-time.  Obviously, if they're not, then you can substitute as appropriate.